# Unable to track desktop application usage in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

We are having a chrome extension that usually tracks what URL's user is visiting and how much time they spend on each URL. We are having a requirement where we can track how much time they spend on desktop applications like excel, Zoom, etc. Is there any way where we can track those using chrome extensions?
Can anyone please help us how resolve the above requirement?

If not chrome extensions how better we can track the desktop applications

Comment: I don't think you can get the information of the native app with the extension.
On Windows, to get the CPU usage rate for each process, execute "get-process | select cpu ,name | Sort-Object -Property cpu -Descending" in PowerShell.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto any suggestion what is the best framework to use if we want to build a desktop application for the above use case

Comment: About ten years ago, when I was an infrastructure engineer, I used Tivoli to monitor application server resources. I don't know much about these days.